# Frontend ways to limit Google Maps API usage

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

So I have a page that is built in ember that I have a map display on the page. This page gets hit alot but certain not enough to hit my quota. Are there some good practices to help reduce the limit the amount of calls I make to the API? I mean when I refresh the page in the network tab its showing up `from disk cache`. So its does not seem to be calling it again. Thoughts?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the API Console Help Page, it states that you can explicitly cap requests in two ways: requests per second per user and requests per day.

To prevent individual users from using up your API quota, limit the number of requests per second per user for an API. Each API includes a default per-user limit, but you can modify that value as described in the [API Console Help Page](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7035610?hl=en&ref_topic=7013279#).

## Note: You can set daily billable limits only on billable APIs. If your project doesn't use any billable APIs, then you can't set daily limits.

To view or change daily billable limits for your API, do the following:

1- Go to the [API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

2- From the projects list, select a project or create a new one.
If the APIs & services page isn't already open, open the left side menu and select APIs & services.

3- Click the name of the API you're interested in.

4- Click Quotas.

5- On the requests per day or requests per 100 seconds per user line, click the edit icon, then enter the preferred total billable daily quota, up to the limit specified by Google.